# Parsing Innerxml in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xml-parsing

I have the following xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<catalog>
 <product description="Cardigan Sweater" product_image="cardigan.jpg">
<catalog_item gender="Men's">
  <item_number>QWZ5671</item_number>
  <price>39.95</price>
  <size description="Medium">
    <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
    <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
  </size>
  <size description="Large">
    <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
    <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
  </size>
</catalog_item>
<catalog_item gender="Women's">
  <item_number>RRX9856</item_number>
  <price>42.50</price>
  <size description="Small">
    <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
    <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
    <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
  </size>
  <size description="Medium">
    <color_swatch image="red_cardigan.jpg">Red</color_swatch>
    <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
    <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
    <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
  </size>
  <size description="Large">
    <color_swatch image="navy_cardigan.jpg">Navy</color_swatch>
    <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
  </size>
  <size description="Extra Large">
    <color_swatch image="burgundy_cardigan.jpg">Burgundy</color_swatch>
    <color_swatch image="black_cardigan.jpg">Black</color_swatch>
  </size>
</catalog_item>
```

Iam able to parse the xml to get the catalog_item(means gender), but i couldn't achieve in parsing the inner elements. Anybody help me in parsing the inner elements and accumulate the items in a dictionary based on gender.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can parse xml using LINQ queries. It's a bit tricky.

First generate some classes for your XML like this

```
public class CatalogItem
    {
        public string item_num { get; set; }
        public double price { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<Size> sizes { get; set; }
    }

    public class Size
    {
        public string sizeDesc { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<ColorSwatch> colorswatches { get; set; }
    }

    public class ColorSwatch
    {
        public string color { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
    }
```

Then parse your XML in the following manner

```
XElement catalogElements = XElement.Parse(xmldata);
var result = from item in catalogElements.Elements("product").Elements("catalog_item")
                     select new CatalogItem()
                     {
                         item_num = item.Element("item_number").Value,
                         price = Double.Parse(item.Element("price").Value),
                         sizes = new ObservableCollection<Size>(from sz in item.Elements("size")
                                select new Size()
                                {
                                    sizeDesc = sz.Attribute("description").Value,
                                    colorswatches = new ObservableCollection<ColorSwatch>(from cs in sz.Elements("color_swatch")
                                                                                        select new ColorSwatch()
                                                                                        {
                                                                                             color = cs.Value,
                                                                                             image = cs.Attribute("image").Value
                                                                                        })
                                })
                     };

  List<CatalogItem> catalogItems = result.ToList();
  var items = catalogItems.First().sizes.First().sizeDesc; //Medium
  var sjdl  = catalogItems.First().sizes.First().colorswatches.First().color; //Red
```